# Do I need to dispose a web service reference in ASP.NET? Can I use a singleton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, singleton, idisposable

Do I really need to dispose a `SoapHttpClientProtocol` object?

Is it better practice to use the instance as a `Singleton` in ASP.Net?

This says that `SoapHttpClientProtocol` is Thread Safe:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.aspx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that it is thread-safe means that using it as singleton **will reduce your site almost to a single-threaded application**.

Proxies - especially for a web application - should always be created as temporary object inside a `using` block (although in WCF it needs to be a different approach). **This approach will have its overhead of creating a proxy every time but is the safest approach.** This will prevent different clients of the ASP.NET application *clashing* with each other or using a *closed or faulted proxy*.